# Using jQuery File Upload to implement images with association on multistep form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be able to submit a form (i.e. project), and redirect to a second step (or page) where users can add photos associated to that project. But how does the form know that these photos will be associated to that project? What do I need to do? Is there a simple tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this if to setup a new route the photo upload on the projects controller. Rails will provide the id for the related project once the action is called.

Routes:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    get  'add_photos'
    post 'upload_photos'
  end
end
```

ProjectsController:

```
# ... change the redirect with the create action to visit your upload page (on success)
def create
  ...
  redirect_to app_photos_project_path(@project), notice: "Created, you can now upload photos"
end

# you'll find the project through the id passed on
def add_photos
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

This is very much simplified but I hope this answers your question and helps to get started ...

Cheers

Comment: Dang, my images that are trying to get uploaded are getting 400 error, bad requests

Comment: I can see in my logs that I'm getting this error: `ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: project:` Do you know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Also, what is the `post 'upload_photos'` for? its not used anywhere?

Comment: The answer does not cover the upload, just your question on how to pass the project. In your second comment you typed 'param' this should be 'params'

Comment: upload_photos stands for the action which carries out the actual upload. This may also be implemented on a different controller since your project has multiple photos. A model ProjectPhoto model could refer to the individual photos and associate those to your projects. In this case you would use a ProjectPhotosController to carry out the upload. There is lot more to it - you'll find very a very good episode on file uploads with jQuery on Ryan Bates Railscasts http://railscasts.com